# How does the Teradata REST API performance compare to other means of querying Teradata?

Tags: odbc, teradata

I'm planning on using the [Teradata Python module](https://developer.teradata.com/tools/reference/teradata-python-module), which can use either the Teradata REST API or ODBC to connect to Teradata. I'm wondering what the performance would be like for REST vs. ODBC connection methods for fairly large data pulls (> 1 million rows, > 1 GB of results).

My company doesn't currently have REST services enabled, so I can't directly test them to compare. [Information on Teradata's site](http://www.teradatamagazine.com/v15n01/Tech2Tech/Driverless-Connectivity/) suggests that the use case for the REST API is more for direct access of Teradata by browsers or web applications, which implies to me that it may not be optimized for queries that return more data than a browser would be expected to handle. I also wonder if JSON overhead will make it less efficient than the ODBC data format for sending query results over the network.

Does anyone have experience with Teradata REST services performance or can point to any comparisons between REST and ODBC for Teradata?

Comment: did you get any solution?